# require lang file in MVC php

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop

In the main view i have this function

```
public function lang($file, $language){
require 'languages/'.$language.'/'. $file . '.php'; 
}
```

Then in the view file home.php i have

```
$this->lang('global','en');
```

The lag file global.php

```
$lang = array (
  'title' => 'mySite',
);
```

Now in the home.php if I use `print_r($lang);` nothing happens. I copy and paste the same script below the array in `global.php` and in `home.php` I see the array. So the file is loaded but why can't I use it `home.php` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public function lang( $file, $language)
{
    require_once("languages/{$language}/{$file}.php");

    return $lang;
}

$lang = $this->lang('global','en');
print_r($lang);
```

I'd suggest caching the results, though, and accessing that way.

```
var $cache = array();

public function lang( $file, $language)
{
    if( !isset( $this->cache[$language][$file] ) )
    {
        require_once("languages/{$language}/{$file}.php");
        $this->cache[$language][$file] = $lang;
    }

    return $this->cache[$language][$file];
}

$lang = $this->lang('global','en');
print_r($lang);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because the scope in which you add the variable is only the `lang()` function.
If you want to us that outside the function , you will have to set it to some object variable.

Here are the changes i would make:

- global.php

  ```
  return array(
      'title' => 'Sitename something'
  );
  ```
- and in the function:

  ```
  public function lang($file, $language)
  {
    if ( empty($this->translations ))
    {
      $this->translation = include 'languages/'.$language.'/'. $file . '.php'; 
    }
  }
  ```

Now you should be able to see the content of that file in `$this->translations` variable. If you want to cache more the one language of file content, you will have to create a two-dimensional array, ans store it there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are loading the lang file from inside a function, which means that `$lang` does not get placed into the global scope but rather the local function scope.

**Minimum required change to make it work (but not a good idea)**

Assuming you *want* `$lang` to be placed inside the global scope, you could do so explicitly:

```
public function lang($file, $language){
    require 'languages/'.$language.'/'. $file . '.php'; 
    $GLOBALS['lang'] = $lang; // "export" to global scope
}
```

**A much better idea**

There are several things that can be improved:

1. The function above writes the contents of the global variable `$lang` "behind the caller's back" -- that's not good design, and it makes the code harder to maintain
2. As it stands, it loads the language file from scratch every time you call it

You can kill both birds with one stone by storing the language file contents inside a `static` local variable and returning it from the function: there is no more writing to the global scope, and the variable keeps its contents so you don't have to reload the language file every time. It would look like this:

```
public function lang($file, $language){
    static $cache = array();
    if (empty($cache[$language][$file])) {
        // load language files on demand
        require 'languages/'.$language.'/'. $file . '.php'; 
        $cache[$language][$file] = $lang;
    }

    return $lang; // return requested data, which is now definitely cached
}
```

And to use it, you would do:

```
$lang = $this->lang('global', 'en');
```

Dumping raw variables into the global scope like this is not always the best idea, but depending on the circumstances (small projects) it might be OK.

Comment: You really should not use `$_GLOBALS` in OOP. It's an extremely bad practice.

Comment: @tereško: There is no conceptual difference between `$_GLOBALS` and Singleton, which is also considered by many to be a bad practice. OTOH, and in relation to your OOP reference, encapsulating data inside an object (which is orthogonal to the global vs singleton decision) to protect it is always better engineering -- but again, unless there is some benefit (unlikely in small projects) blindly going for "moar engineering" is not something I would endorse.

Comment: Projects have to be maintained. Introduction of global state will mean "moar maintenance". Especially if you come back to it after 6 month and cannot remember where each of your globals was set.

Comment: Lol. In question was ugly "require" inside function, but in answer Jon suggests to add GLOBALS, to make code worse. It should be a joke.

Comment: The new version is much better (though, i still would avoid the use of `static` for this). +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this in home.php :

```
$Lang = $this->lang('global','en');
```

and this

```
public function lang($file, $language){
    return require 'languages/'.$language.'/'. $file . '.php'; 
}
```